# Conversion error when changing datetime field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When trying to update a `datetime` field I get the following message

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

SQL:

```
begin tran
update CCDocumentDCH 
set DocDate = '2013-10-28 12:17:00.000'
where DocNo = '1346815'
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: The statement works in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server (which is just a guess), try doing an explicit conversion:

```
update CCDocumentDCH
    set DocDate = convert(datetime, '2013-10-28 12:17:00.000', 121)
    where DocNo = '1346815';
```

I do believe that there exist international formats that will interpret "XXXX-XX-XX" as "YYYY-DD-MM".  An explicit conversion fixes this problem.